# Unable to use ObjectListView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, wrapper, objectlistview

I just downloaded  [ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx). After adding the dll file when the objectListView is placed on my vb.net form it shows an error

> Type 'BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView' is not defined.

How to solve this problem  ? 
I am using VS2010

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are missing a reference.

If you added the project source code, then you need to right-click on the project and select `Add Reference...`, select the Projects tab, and choose the ObjectListView project.

If you are just using the DLL, then you need to right-click on the project and select `Add Reference...`, select the Browse tab, and select the DLL file.

**Update**

Based on the screenshot, the issue is that ObjectListView requires the full .Net Framework, not the client profile.

To resolve this, right-click on the project, select `Properties`, then select `.Net Framework 4` in the `Target framework` dropdown list (it will currently be set to `.Net Framework 4 Client Profile`).

Comment: I am using the DLL, thats exactly how I have done but I still get that error message

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded the full demo package and verified that it would run. I then went to the Toolbox Right-Clicked and Selected Choose Items... under .Net Framework Components I then browsed to the folder that has the ObjectListView.dll in it and selected it. This added the component to the Containers group on the Toolbox.  I then added ObjectListView to my form and it worked correctly. Check and make sure your project references have ObjectListView in them.
i.e.

[image]